# MySQL subquery returns more than one row and errors out

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL statement here I need rows that are within a certain column to be divided into rows... but when I retrieve the data is returns the error

> 1 Subquery returns more than 1 row

:( please help here is my query

```
(select 
    (SELECT 
            (meta_value)
        FROM
            main_postmeta
        WHERE
            meta_key = 'project_year') as Year,
    (SELECT 
            (meta_value)
        FROM
            main_postmeta
        WHERE
            meta_key = 'project_gapp_city') as Location,
    (SELECT 
            (meta_value)
        FROM
            main_postmeta
        WHERE
            meta_key = 'project_title') as Title
FROM
    main_postmeta
WHERE
    main_postmeta.post_id = '1423'
ORDER BY meta_value desc);
```

Comment: As per error, subqueries can contain only 1 row, which also makes sense when you look at it - imagine what would happen if 1st subquery returns 0 rows, 2nd returns 1 and 3rd returns 30. Without your tables, data and what you expect - there's no way to properly help you. Maybe you should ask the question in form of what you tried, what you expect and how your data looks like.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: please provie tables with some sample data and your expected output

Comment: I would suspect that you need to check the value of main_postmeta.post_id in each of the sub queries as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a pivoted result set.

```
select 
     case when meta_key='project_year' then meta_value else null end as `YEAR`
   , case when meta_key='project_gapp_city' then meta_value else null end as `LOCATION`
   , case when meta_key='project_title' then meta_value else null end as `Title`
from main_postmeta
where main_postmeta.post_id = '1423'
order by meta_value desc
```

If the values fetching are grouped under a single `post_id` then:

```
select 
     max ( case when meta_key='project_year' 
                     then meta_value 
                else null 
           end ) as `YEAR`
   , max ( case when meta_key='project_gapp_city' 
                     then meta_value 
                else null
           end ) as `LOCATION`
   , max ( case when meta_key='project_title' 
                     then meta_value 
                else null
           end ) as `Title`
from main_postmeta
where main_postmeta.post_id = '1423'
 order by meta_value desc
```

Comment: thanks man, it worked as like a charm I just didnt think outside the box haha :) thanks a mill!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to do a join for each meta value, something like this:-

```
SELECT a.meta_value, b.meta_value, c.meta_value
FROM main_postmeta a 
INNER JOIN main_postmeta b ON a.post_id = b.meta_key AND b.meta_key = 'project_gapp_city'
INNER JOIN main_postmeta c ON a.post_id = c.meta_key AND c.meta_key = 'project_title'
WHERE a.post_id = '1423' 
AND a.meta_key = 'project_year'
ORDER BY meta_value DESC
```

Depending on what you want to do with the results you might also be able to do something like this:-

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', meta_key, meta_value))
FROM main_postmeta a 
WHERE a.post_id = '1423' 
AND a.meta_key IN ( 'project_gapp_city', 'project_year', 'project_title')
```

and then explode out the keys and values.